# lualatex luasec/luasocket

Tags: luatex, lua

I hope this isn't frustrating since there are already other posts regarding a similar question, but somehow nothing I read so far works.

As I'm under Arch Linux, I installed `lua` and `luarocks` via `pacman` (maybe relevant in terms of paths where the packages got installed). Then I installed via `luarocks install --local --lua-version=5.3 luasec` (luaversion specified since otherwise the lib is installed for 5.4). As seen with

```bash
$ luarocks --local --lua-version 5.3 list

Rocks installed for Lua 5.3 in /home/lukas/.luarocks
----------------------------------------------------

luasec
   1.0.2-1 (installed) - /home/lukas/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.3

luasocket
   3.0rc1-2 (installed) - /home/lukas/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.3
```

the rock is installed. Executing a short test programm

```lua
$ cat main2.lua
-- output from luarocks --lua-version 5.3 path converted
package.path='/usr/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua;/home/lukas/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/home/lukas/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua'
package.cpath='/usr/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so;./?.so;/home/lukas/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.3/?.so'

local https = require 'ssl.https'

print("Hi")
$ lua5.3 main2.lua
Hi
```

works.

If I now try to run this within `lualatex`

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{luapackageloader} % use the default lua path as well

\directlua{dofile("main2.lua")}

\begin{document}

hi

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```tex
/home/lukas/.luarocks/shar
e/lua/5.3/ssl.lua:8: module 'ssl.core' not found:
        no field package.preload['ssl.core']
        [lua searcher]: module not found: 'ssl.core'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.3/ssl/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.3/ssl/core/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.3/ssl/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.3/ssl/core/init.lua'
        no file './ssl/core.lua'
        no file './ssl/core/init.lua'
        no file '/home/lukas/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/ssl/core.lua'
        no file '/home/lukas/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/ssl/core/init.lua'
        [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'ssl.core'
        [lua C searcher]: module not found: 'ssl.core'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.3/ssl/core.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
        no file './ssl/core.so'
        no file '/home/lukas/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.3/ssl/core.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/lukas/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/ssl.lua:8: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/lukas/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/ssl/https.lua:10: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        main2.lua:4: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.5 \directlua{dofile("main2.lua")}
```

I'm already using the `luapackageloader` tex-package to be able to search the "normal" lua path as well.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work with lualatex?

(I've checked other lua libs as well, `date` or `lunajson` seem to be working this way so maybe it is a thing with openssl, but in this case as well I've got no idea what the exact cause might be)

Answer (score 6):

1. You don't have to install `luasocket` since `luasocket` is automatically provided by LuaTeX.
2. If you want to load C based libraries in LuaLaTeX, you have to run `lualatex` with the `--shell-escape` option since it allows to execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew this. `lualatex --shell-escape master2.tex` is working (And `luasocket` for the most part is installed with `luarocks` as a dependency of `luasec`)